# Creating Login Script With PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am attempting to create a simple log in system on my hosted web page. I have a MySQL database and table created using phpMyAdmin. The database, HTML and PHP files are hosted on the same server. I am able to add users, and the account information appears in the table. The issue is with logging in. I always get a "Log In Failed error". The tutorial I have used is [located here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html). I have checked and re-checked for mistypings, and I do not believe that is the issue. I believe the issue is related to the `fetchColumn()` command. From what I have researched, this command grabs the next row, which doesn't make sense to me because the username, password, and userID are all located in the same row, just different columns.

This is the form where the user submits the information, and then the login script is called. There are two forms in the code below; the first form is what is important in this problem.

```
    <?php

/*** begin our session ***/
session_start();

/*** set a form token ***/
$form_token = md5( uniqid('auth', true) );

/*** set the session form token ***/
$_SESSION['form_token'] = $form_token;
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Log In Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formstyle.css">
</head>

<header>
Log In Page
</header>

<body>
<h2>Log In</h2>
<form action="login_submit.php" method="post">
<fieldset id="forms" >
<p>
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" maxlength="20"/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="20"/>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>

<h2>Create Account</h2>
<form action="adduser_submit.php" method="post">
<fieldset id="forms" >
<p>
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" maxlength="20"/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="20"/>
</p>
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the login_submit script.

```
        <?php

    /*** begin our session ***/
    session_start();

    /*** check if the user is already logged in ***/
    if(isset( $_SESSION['userID'] ))
    {
        $message = 'User is already logged in';
    }
    /*** check that both the username and password have been submitted ***/
    if(!isset( $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
    {
        $message = 'Please enter a valid username and password';
    }
    /*** check the username is the correct length ***/
    elseif (strlen( $_POST['username']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['username']) < 4)
    {
        $message = 'Incorrect Length for Username';
    } `enter code here`
    /*** check the password is the correct length ***/
    elseif (strlen( $_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 4)
    {
        $message = 'Incorrect Length for Password';
    }
    /*** check the username has only alpha numeric characters ***/
    elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['username']) != true)
    {
        /*** if there is no match ***/
        $message = "Username must be alpha numeric";
    }
    else
    {
        /*** if we are here the data is valid and we can insert it into database ***/
        $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        /*** now we can encrypt the password ***/
        $password = sha1( $password );

        /*** connect to database ***/
        /*** mysql hostname ***/
        $mysql_hostname = 'localhost';

        /*** mysql username ***/
        $mysql_username = 'neticl5';

        /*** mysql password ***/
        $mysql_password = 'corrupted707';

        /*** database name ***/
        $mysql_dbname = 'neticl5_apptest';

        try
        {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
            /*** $message = a message saying we have connected ***/

            /*** set the error mode to excptions ***/
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            /*** prepare the select statement ***/
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT userID, username, password FROM useraccounts 
                        WHERE username = :username AND password = :password');

            /*** bind the parameters ***/
            $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);

            /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
            $stmt->execute();

            /*** check for a result ***/
            $userID = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        /*** if we have no result then fail boat ***/
            if($userID == false)
            {
                    $message = 'Login Failed';
            }
        /*** if we do have a result, all is well ***/
            else
            {
                    /*** set the session user_id variable ***/
                    $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;

                    /*** tell the user we are logged in ***/
                    $message = 'You are now logged in';
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            /*** if we are here, something has gone wrong with the database ***/
            $message = 'We are unable to process your request. Please try again later';
        }
    }
    ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do i suppose to read that tutorial ? huh

Comment: The whitespace before the PHP opening tags (`<?php`) are problematic. You cannot send *any* output [before calling `session_open()`](http://php.net/session_start#refsect1-function.session-start-notes).

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question. The password field in the database was not set to the correct length. The field for the user requires it to be a maximum of 20. The field in the database needed to be set to the correct limit for encryption.